# (CMake build) fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'glew.lib'

Tags: c++, cmake

I am working on a game engine and have recently tried to create a CMakeLists.txt to build the project. I managed to create a cmakelist which configured and generated but when I tried to run the generate .sln in visual studios I got the following error:

`fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'glew.lib'`

My game engine uses the external libraries glew and glfw. Here is my cmakelist file:

````
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(GameEngine)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Engine/source)

set(ENGINE_SOURCES ${SOURCE_DIR}/core/Engine.cpp
           ${SOURCE_DIR}/graphics/gl_types/IndexBuffer.cpp
           ${SOURCE_DIR}/graphics/gl_types/VertexArray.cpp
           ${SOURCE_DIR}/graphics/gl_types/VertexBuffer.cpp
           ${SOURCE_DIR}/graphics/renderer/Camera.cpp
           ${SOURCE_DIR}/graphics/renderer/Shader.cpp
           ${SOURCE_DIR}/graphics/renderer/Texture.cpp
           ${SOURCE_DIR}/graphics/renderer/Window.cpp
           ${SOURCE_DIR}/vendor/stb_image/stb_image.cpp)

add_library(engine STATIC ${ENGINE_SOURCES})
target_include_directories(engine PUBLIC ${SOURCE_DIR})


set(glfw3_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/GLFW/lib/cmake/glfw3)
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)

set(glew_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/GLEW)
find_library(glew glew32s "${glew_DIR}/lib/Release/Win32")

include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${glew_DIR}/include)

target_link_libraries(
        engine
        glfw
        glew
)

set(GAME_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Game/source)
set(GAME_SOURCES ${GAME_DIR}/main.cpp)

add_executable(engine_game ${GAME_SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(engine_game engine)```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `find_library` which sets variables. You have to use them as such:

```
target_link_libraries(
        engine
        ${glfw_LIBRARIES}
        ${glew}
)
```

I assume `glfw_LIBRARIES` is the variable set by `find_package(glfw)`.

Comment: Using the library names as variables the program was no longer looking for .lib files but now I have  a linking error ```fatal error LNK1120: 48 unresolved externals```

Comment: This means that you have another library missing. Maybe it's not the correct name for `glfw`. You have to check the documentation to see the proper name. Also check int he configuration (`CMakeCache.txt`) that the entries have the value you expect.

Comment: Yes glfw wasn't being linked properly and I needed a preprocessor definition GLEW_STATIC to be defined for my glew library. Now my program works thanks.